# Trouble extracting component to file using Glean

Tags: vscode-extensions

[Image of VSCODE environment and error message from Glean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMQVP.png)

I'm currently trying to use the Glean extension to extract the component to another file I don't understand why it duplicates my path and gives me that error message this is the first time I'm using Glean. I tried reading documentation but I'm still a bit lost..

Answer (score 0):

The **EINVAL: invalid argument, mkdir error** occurs in the [Glean](https://github.com/wix-incubator/vscode-glean) extension as we select the absolute path for the new file/component.

When using the extension to extract part of the code to a new Component, always select the ***relative path*** to the file you are in.

Say you are working in the folder, **D:/Workspace/Project/Frontend/Pages/**, and you want to extract part of the code in a file, **List.jsx** to another file in the same folder.

You can select the part of the code you want to extract, click the **Lightbulb** on the left, and select the option **Extract Component to File**.

A dropdown options shows all the file paths where you want to add the new file/component.

If you select the first option **D:/Workspace/Project/Frontend/Pages/**, an error occurs as you are trying to *duplicate* the file path. This is why you get the error. This has also been raised as a bug in their repository.

You need to scroll down, choose the relative path **./Pages/** (*. as it's in the same folder as the previous file*), and enter the filename. No error will be there and the code will be extracted to a new component.

Hope this helps!